# Aggregate two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, aggregate

Let's say I've got these two arrays:

```
const initial: Array<GivenObj> = [
  {name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}
];

const toBeMerged: Array<GivenObj> = [
  {name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30},
  {name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];
```

These two arrays contain different values, but similar keys. I need to aggregate this data to a single array that will contain both of their values, but uniquely.

In code, the two arrays above should be aggregated as follows:

```
const aggregated: Array<GivenObj> = [
  {name: 'a', times: 85, other: 80},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 25, other: 22},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];
```

I was wondering what's the best way to aggregate data between two arrays.

Comment: You'll need to loop through, find duplicates, and do the math. There isn't an out-of-the-box method to actually combine property values. Have you tried?

Comment: @isherwood Indeed I tried. But it felt like someone else's solution might be more efficiant than mine.

Comment: post your code then please

Comment: The result for `times` for `a` should be 85, and `c` is wrong for both values.

Comment: who is downvoting almost all answers ?

Comment: It's a code dump. No-one except jmcgriz bothered to explain what their code does.

Comment: @Andy thanks, values are fixed.

Comment: @EliyaCohen Chances are the downvote was because you didnt supply any code. You should show what you tried, even if it doesnt work, when asking. That way answerers can gauge your skill level and advise appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the given data and look for same `name`, then update, otherwise add a new object.

It takes

- a new array with items from `initial` and `toBeMerged`,
- reducing the items by

  - looking for an item with same `name` in the accumulator `r`,
  - checking if the item is not found, then return a new array with collected itms and a copy of the actual object
  - otherwise increment the needed properties with some values.

```js
const
    initial = [{ name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50 }, { name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15 }, { name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12 }],
    toBeMerged = [{ name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30 }, { name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10 }, { name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10 }],
    merged = [...initial, ...toBeMerged].reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(p => o.name === p.name);
        if (!temp) return [...r, { ...o }];
        temp.times += o.times;
        temp.other += o.other;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: @Shidersz No idea. Almost all of the answers have been downvoted for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

I'd approach this by merging the two arrays, then running a reduce against that combined array.

Inside the reduce, it first checks to see if an entry with that name exists, if not it pushes that entry to the result array. If it does find an existing entry, it creates any property that doesn't exist, and adds the values of any numerical properties that already exist. This should be flexible enough for whatever your actual use case is.

```js
const initial = [
  {name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}
];

const toBeMerged = [
  {name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30},
  {name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];

const result = [ ...initial, ...toBeMerged ].reduce((arr, t) => {
  let existing = arr.filter(x => x.name == t.name)[0]
  if(!existing) arr.push(t)
  else {
    const keys = Object.keys(t)
    keys.forEach(key => {
      if(!existing.hasOwnProperty(key)) existing[key] = t[key]
      else if(typeof existing[key] === "number") existing[key] += t[key]
    })
  }
  
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have approached this problem in the past.

1. Create a `final` array, which will contain the final result.
2. The arrays are merged using the Array `concat` method
3. The concatenated array is sorted by the `name` property, meaning that all the a's will be in order, then the b's, etc.
4. The `forEach` method is used to iterate through the concatenated, sorted array. If the current element has the same `name` property as the last element of the `final` array, then add the numeric properties of `el` to the last element of the `final` array. Otherwise, add `el` to the end of the final array.

```js
const initial = [
  {name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}
];

const toBeMerged = [
  {name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30},
  {name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];

let final = [];

initial.concat(toBeMerged).sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name).forEach(el => {
  if (final.length > 0 && el.name === final[final.length - 1].name) {
    final[final.length - 1].times += el.times;
    final[final.length - 1].other += el.other;
  } else {
    final.push(el);
  }
})

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

1. First merge both the array's using `concat`.
2. Now on the concated array using `reduce` we check if the object property is already present in `output` than we add `times` and `other` in existing property if not than we add a new property.

```js
const initial= [{name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},{name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},{name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}];
const toBeMerged= [{name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30},{name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},{name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}];
let temp = initial.concat(toBeMerged)

let op = temp.reduce((output,current)=>{
  if( output[current.name] ){
    output[current.name].times += current.times
    output[current.name].other += current.other
  } else{
    output[current.name] = current;
  }
  return output;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
const initial = [
  {name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}
];

const toBeMerged = [
  {name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30},
  {name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];

//console.log(initial);

function arrayUnique(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i].name === a[j].name)
            {
                a[i].times +=a[j].times;
                a[i].other +=a[j].other;
                a.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}


    // Merges both arrays and gets unique items
var array = arrayUnique(initial.concat(toBeMerged));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one approach using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) over the new array to be merged. If a new object to be merged already exists (i.e the `name` property match for some object), we increment the rest of the matching properties and add the non-existing ones, otherwise we push the entire new object:

```js
const initial = [
  {name: 'a', times: 40, other: 50},
  {name: 'b', times: 10, other: 15},
  {name: 'c', times: 15, other: 12}
];

const toBeMerged = [
  {name: 'a', times: 45, other: 30, another: 76},
  {name: 'c', times: 10, other: 10},
  {name: 'd', times: 23, other: 10}
];

let newArray = toBeMerged.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    let found = res.findIndex(x => x.name === curr.name);

    if (found >= 0)
    {
        res[found] = Object.keys(curr).reduce((r, c) =>
        {
           r[[c]] = (r[[c]] && c !== 'name') ? r[[c]] + curr[[c]] : curr[[c]];
           return r;
        }, res[found]);
    }
    else
    {
        res.push(curr);
    }

    return res;

}, initial);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using spread operator, destructuring, Array#reduce, Object#values and Map

```js
const initial=[{name:'a',times:40,other:50},{name:'b',times:10,other:15},{name:'c',times:15,other:12}];const toBeMerged=[{name:'a',times:45,other:30},{name:'c',times:10,other:10},{name:'d',times:23,other:10}]

const res = [...[...initial, ...toBeMerged]
.reduce((a,{name,times,other})=>{
    const b = a.get(name);
    return a.set(name,{name, times: (b?b.times:0) + times, other: (b?b.other:0) + other});
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(res);
```